spfx extension code to track complete sharepoint online site and its modern pages
i am trying to build spfx extension to track sharepoint online site. here is the code.
How can i fix the errors please???
"error @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any: Unexpected any. Specify a different type"
Or if any one can suggest only a hard coded lines in the extension, that will call google analytics and compile properly, it will work as well.
Thank you
    import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
    import { BaseApplicationCustomizer } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
    const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'SpfxanalyticsApplicationCustomizer';
    export interface ISpfxanalyticsApplicationCustomizerProperties {
      trackingID: string;
    }
    export default class SpfxanalyticsApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ISpfxanalyticsApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
      public onInit(): Promise<void> {
        Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized SpfxanalyticsApplicationCustomizer`);
        // Add Google Analytics script
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${this.properties.trackingID}`;
        script.async = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = () => {
          (window as any).dataLayer = (window as any).dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(...args: any[]): void {
            (window as any).dataLayer.push(args);
          }
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', this.properties.trackingID);
        };
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
    }

i tried to do "Gulp Build" and getting errors
node -v is 20.11.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
